# redux not being connected to react native properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Being a newbie to react native ,I am finding it difficult to connect my redux with react native and make it work. After javascript bundle finishes ,I see an error "can't read property type of undefined" or "could not find store in either the context or props of "connect".Either wrap the root component in a  or explicitly pass "store" as prop.I don't see any of the console.log working  except for reducer .
Here is the action that I am using

```
import {ADD_PLACE,DELETE_PLACE,DESELECT_PLACE,SELECT_PLACE} from './actiontypes';

export const addPLace =(placeName) =>{
  console.log('addPLace is being dispatched now');
   console.log('In addPLace reducer');
  return{
    type:ADD_PLACE,
    payload:{
      placeName:placeName
    }
  };
};

export const deletePlace =()=>{
  return{
    type:DELETE_PLACE
  };
}
export const selectedPlace =(key) =>{
  return{
    type:SELECT_PLACE,
    payload:{
      placekey:key
    }
  };
};
export const deselectPlace =()=>{
  return {
    type:DESELECT_PLACE
  };
};
```

Here is the reducer part

```
import {ADD_PLACE,DELETE_PLACE,SELECT_PLACE,DESELECT_PLACE} from '../actions/actiontypes';
import PlaceImage from "../../../src/assets/download.jpeg";

const INITIAL_STATE={
  places:[],
  selectedPlace:null
}
const reducer =(action,state=INITIAL_STATE) =>{
  console.log('INside reducer');
  console.log(action);
  switch(action.type){
    case ADD_PLACE:
    return {
      ...state,
      places:state.places.concat({
        key:Math.random(),
        name:action.payload.placeName,
        image:placeImage
      })
    };
    case DELETE_PLACE:
    return{
      ...state,
      places:state.places.filter(place =>{
        return place.key !== state.selectedPlace.key;
      }),
      selectPlace:null
    };
    case SELECT_PLACE:
    return{
      ...state,
      selectedPlace:state.places.find(place=>{
        return place.key ===action.payload.placekey;
      })
    };
    case DESELECT_PLACE:
    return{
      ...state,
      selectPlace:null
    };

    default:
        return state;
  }
}
export default reducer;
```

Here is the App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";

import store from './src/store/reducers/index.js';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
//import {createStore} from 'redux';
//import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Home from './Home.js';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('inside App');
    console.log(store);
       return (
           <Provider store={store}>
               <Home />
           </Provider>
       );
   }

}
```

Here is the Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
//import ListItem from './src/components/ListItem';
import PlaceInput from "./src/components/PlaceInput";
import PlaceList from "./src/components/PlaceList";
//import PlaceImage from "./src/assets/download.jpeg";
import PlaceDetail from "./src/components/PlaceDetail";
//import configureStore from './src/store/reducers/index.js';
//import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
//import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addPLace,deletePlace,selectedPlace,deselectPlace} from './src/store/actions';

//const store=configureStore();

class Home extends React.Component {

   placeAddedHandler =val=>{
     console.log('Val is ',val);
     console.log(val);
    this.props.onAddPlace(val);
  };

  placeSelectHandler =id=>{
    console.log('id is');
    this.props.onSelectPlace(id);
  };
  placeDeleteHandler =() =>{
    console.log('inside delete handler');
  this.props.onDeletePlace();
  };
  modelClosedHandler =() =>{
    console.log('iinside close handler');
    this.props.onDeslectPlace();
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Inside render function');
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
      <PlaceInput onPlaceAdded={this.placeAddedHandler}/>
      <PlaceList places={this.props.places} onItemSelected={this.placeSelectHandler}/>
      <PlaceDetail
      selectedPlace={this.props.selectedPlace}
      onItemDeleted={this.placeDeleteHandler}
      onModalClosed={this.modelClosedHandler}
      />
      </View>


    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding:30,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
});
const mapStateToProps=state => {
  console.log('Inside mapStateToProps ');
  console.log(state );
  return {
    places:state.places.places,
    selectedPlace:state.places.selectPlace
  };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
  return {
   onAddPlace:(name)=>dispatch(addPLace(name)),
   onDeletePlace:()=>dispatch(deletePlace()),
   onSelectPlace:(id)=>dispatch(selectedPlace(id)),
   onDeslectPlace:()=>dispatch(deselectPlace())
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Link to github repo of project at this moment 
[github link](https://github.com/kolaveridi/PlacesApp/tree/219b364e0203d1deb89d10ced3e2e0272b094f43)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have made a small import/export error.

In your `reducers/index.js` you are exporting it as a non default value which you are trying to import as default value in `App.js.`

`import store from './src/store/reducers/index.js';`

should be

`import {store} from './src/store/reducers/index.js';`

Let me know if it works.